# Generating excel file with dynamic name

Tags: visualforce, excel

I am trying to generate a excel sheet from a VF page. i am using

```
contenttype="application/x-excel#filename.xls"
```

on the page tag. These work perfectly fine. I just need a way to have the filenames dynamically generated or a simple adding of todays datetime to the end of the filename.

Tried adding
     contenttype="application/x-excel#filename" +"{!todays}"+".xls"

and it didnt allow 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do the trick!

```
contenttype="application/x-excel#filename{!TODAY()}.xls"
```

Results in ...

[image]

You are able to use bindings and/or formula functions in attribute values, even those on the apex:page tag!

Comment: Nice! Fasted Q&A in the world! :)

Comment: i love this site :)

Comment: Same! Please be sure to mark the answer as resolved. ;-)