# Possible Values for renderAs in VisualForce?

Tags: visualforce

What formats are available for `renderAs` in VisualForce? For example, I am already aware of PDF and HTML.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the only option for `renderAs` on `apex:page` is PDF.

> The name of any supported content converter. Currently PDF is the only supported content converter. Setting this attribute to "pdf" renders the page as a PDF.

See here:
https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm

Answer (score 3):

You may instead wish to examine the `contentType` attribute of `apex:page`. Here is a good [link](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_styling_content_type.htm). Money quote (the MIME link has quite an exhaustive list):

> The ContentType attribute takes a Multipurpose Internet Mail Extension (MIME) media type as a value, such as application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv, or image/gif. Browsers can behave unpredictably if you set an invalid ContentType. For more information about valid MIME media types, see http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/.

As a bonus, this approach also allows you to [specify a filename](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12788/generating-excel-file-with-dynamic-name).

Answer (score 0):

you may not use renderas but you can get the data in the vfpage as EXCEl.

```
        <apex:page contentType="application/x-excel#RenderAsTestFile.xls" 

           standardController="Account">

<apex:pageBlock >
   <!-- <apex:pageblockTable value="{!YOURList from Controller}" var="v" border="1" 
                  columnsWidth="100px,200px,150px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8">
        <apex:column headerValue="Id">{!v.Name}</apex:column>
    </apex:pageblockTable>-->
</apex:pageBlock>
```